# paste multiple images on the surface of a cylinder in ios and scroll it

Tags: ios, image, scroll, cylindrical

I need a scroll view where multiple images are arranged in a cylindrical manner and on scrolling, the images should revolve like images on a glass cup. The cup should be slightly tilted so that the image at the back can also be seen. I tried using iCarousel for this, but the image does not curl and the tilt doesn't work. Since my images are larger it must be significant.

As I was searching, I came across image warping using OpenGL. Can it be used to create the desired effect?

Comment: If your question is can OpenGL do this. Yes it can.

Comment: I am practically in a tight schedule and I haven't used OpenGL. @bandejapaisa can you please suggest any method to complete this. I have thought of using [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) cylindrical method and bending the view to get the desired effect. May I know how to bend a view into a curved surface?

Comment: I have achieved cylinder effect using iCarousel, but the images on those cylinder are plane rectangles. I want to achieve a bend in the image so that it appears to be pasted on the cylinder. Please suggest a solution. Can CALayer be used to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the desired effect by using iCarousel cylindrical layout. I stripped those images into multiple image strips and I have added it to the carousel view and managed the spacing to get the completeness of the cylinder. It works like a gem.